# how to get status result from notebook that I called in databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks

In databricks in parent notebook I called the child notebook with some parameters:`dbutils.notebook.run("/Users/some_user_name/nb_master_gold_dimension_load", 5,{"param1":"val1","param2":"val2" })`.
How to get the status of the child's notebook while I'm in the parent?

In the parent notebook I try to get the result of executing the child notebook by assigning it to a variable:
[image]
And in result I got `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dbutils.notebook.run` returns whatever value that is provided by the called notebook via call to the `dbutils.notebook.exit` function ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#run-example)).  (Please note that `dbutils.notebook.exit` doesn't work correctly for notebooks with streams (even with the `Trigger.once`))

Another approach would be to refactor your notebooks workflow into a multitask job with the [cluster reuse](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/02/04/saving-time-and-costs-with-cluster-reuse-in-databricks-jobs.html) and passing [context between the tasks](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/08/02/sharing-context-between-tasks-in-databricks-workflows.html).

Comment: Thank you for this info! Does my approach correct when i try to assign to variable like this: `status = dbutils.notebook.run("/Users/some_user_name/nb_master_gold_dimension_load", 5,{"param1":"val1","param2":"val2" })` and print the `status`?

Comment: yes, that's correct approach

Comment: Thx. Now my child's notebook runs correctly. Any thoughts why the `status` variable returns `None`?

Comment: what are you returning from the child notebook?

Comment: if you mean something inside child notebook so I just have some code with try-except construction.  And in the parent I just use code like above: `status = dbutils.notebook.run("/Users/some_user_name/nb_master_gold_dimension_load", 5,{"param1":"val1","param2":"val2" }) print (status)` and as a result I see `None` after printing.

Comment: I meant that you can't return things like Dataframe, etc. - it should be only string, not longer that 1k

Comment: take a look at the screenshot, I've updated the question.

Comment: Show the code how do you return results. In the child notebook

Comment: Worked just fine. Child notebook: `dbutils.widgets.text("param1", ""); arg = dbutils.widgets.get("param1"); dbutils.notebook.exit(f"Hello {arg}")`, Caller notebook: `status = dbutils.notebook.run("./Child", 300, {"param1":"world"}); print(status)` prints `Hello world`

Comment: I get it. I don't have `dbutils.notebook.exit` statement in the child notebook. So nothing is passed to the parent one. After I've updated the child I got the status in the parent.
Thx for your help!